# Unity3d Show count operations in Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am using Unity3d.
I am writing shader.
How to show count operations in shader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see the instruction count of a shader in Unity, select the shader in the project. (Here I'm selecting one of NGUI's shaders for example)

[image]

Then in the inspector you should see a button "Open Compiled Shader".

[image]

Clicking on this will open the compiled shader and in the opened file you should be able to find the instruction count on lines marked `# ... instructions`.

[image]

Comment: How to open custom(my) shader as compiled shader?